# jQuery POST to PHP doesn't get to success function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a simple jQuery post function that calls PHP script in order to return value from the database.

In Firebug I see that the PHP file is being called with 200 OK status, however the success function in JS is not being called.

To test the problem I have changed the PHP to only echo a simple string, but it doesn't work as well.

When I view the PHP file directly in the browser I do see the echoed string.

Here is the JS code:

```
$.post(PATH + "load.php", { id: _id },
    function (data) {
        console.log("LOADED " + data);
});
```

And here is the simple PHP code:

```
<?
echo "bla bla bla"
?>
```

I don't know what the problem is.
My HTML+JS file is local and it calls an online PHP file. Maybe this is the reason?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your server allows you to use short-hand PHP tags? i.e. when you run the PHP file, does it echo the output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My HTML+JS file is local and it calls an online PHP file. Maybe this is the reason?

Answer: **Yes**
Reason: **Same origin policy** rule

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

**Grant Thomas** suggested a possible workaround: you can delegate the call to a method on same-origin server which calls external resource.

Comment: Possible workaround: delegate the call to a method on same-origin server which calls external resource.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on the workaround? Do you have an example maybe?

Comment: @Light Do you really need to call another server with ajax?

Comment: Eventually it will be on the same server, but while developing it will be difficult to do it online and I must have the files locally...